# statusCode for Alamofire4

Tags: ios, switch-statement, alamofire

all.
I study iOS and alamofire.

there are error about status Code.

`case 200...299: ->` error code: Cannot convert value of type 'CountableClosedRange' to type 'Int' in coercion

if i change it to case .Success: ->  Enum case 'Success' not found in type 'Int?'

what is problem? TT

this is coding.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let params = ["username": "ryulstory", "password": "123!"]
        var rTest = Alamofire.request(self.authLoginUrl, method: .post, parameters: params)
            .responseJSON{ response in
                print(response.request)  // original URL request
                print(response.response) // URL response
                print(response.data)     // server data
                print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

                let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode

                switch statusCode {
                case 200 ... 299 :
                    let jsonData = JSON(response.data!)
                    let token = jsonData["token"].string!
                    print(token)

                    self.keychain["token"] = token
                }
                       }

    }
```

Comment: if you are getting 200 as status code that mean your API call is successfully done. clarify what exactly you need to do

Comment: @Suryakant yes, right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is misleading, the issue you are facing is because of optional chaining as of `response` is optional `statusCode` is also optional wrapped its value using [`Nil-Coalescing Operator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72) and you all set to go.

```
let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode ?? 0

switch statusCode {
    case 200 ... 299 :
        let jsonData = JSON(response.data!)
        let token = jsonData["token"].string!
        print(token)
        self.keychain["token"] = token
}
```